# Knime workflow run set one by one

Tags: knime

Sir,
i need run same workflow DB table creator or DB table load and sp call.
but there have some problem when workflow run execute all then DB loader and Table creater run Same time.I want run first table creator then db loader is it possible any one help pls 
[image: workflow showing the problem]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you corretly you want nodes to be exectucted after each other, so a node B shoud wait for node A to be finished. You you can use the "Flow Variable Ports" (see first post on https://www.knime.com/blog/tips-tricks-for-using-knime-analytics-platform-today-bunny-ears-metanodes-co) as kind of flow control.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just connect them with a variable flow connection:

- Start dragging from the upper-right corner of the Table Creator
- Connect to the upper-left corner of the DB Loader node

You can also select from the context menu the `Show Flow Variable Ports` option to make it easier:
[image: Option to Show Flow Variable Ports]

Result:
[image: Flow variable ports connected]